# Ubuntu 18.04 network stops working and requires restart

Tags: networking, restart

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 a month ago and at times the network connection stops working and i have to restart it ( turn it off and on from the UI, not pc restart ). And it works after, but sometimes it works for hours or days, sometimes it keeps disconnecting and I have to restart it every 5 minutes. I
ve tried setting the ip manually, setting DNS, having ipv6 on and off but still no luck. I'm on a wired connection.
I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: I did face this issue in the beginning, but they fixed it after an update. Is your OS up to date. If not try updating and wait

Comment: Yeah, i keep it up to date but still nothing. Drivers are updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. turn on the connectivity checking option in privacy

   [image]
2. restart the network-manager

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Pablo Bianchi for posting this. It fixed my problem that happened right after an update got applied today.

I upvoted you, but since I have a reputation under 15, the site won't post the upvote. Same goes for commenting. Need a rep of 50.